# C#, dynamic object names?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a list of objects

```
List<dogClass> DogList = new List<dogClass>();
```

and I want to automatically add objects to it, like

```
dogClass myDog1 = new dogClass();
DogList.Add(myDog1);
```

then myDog2, myDog3, etc. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Can you be more clear on your question? I'm unsure what you're asking for... do you want to be able to add many objects at once to the list? E.g. List<dogClass> dogList = new List<dogClass> {dog1, dog2, dog3}; ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't *need* them to have a name you could try this.

```
DogList.Add(new dogClass());
```

Otherwise you can't dynamically name variables like that.  However, you could use a [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) to associate the string "myDog1" etc to a value.

Comment: So basically, if you have a form where you want to grab various field names and check their .Text property, you have to manually enter every field name into the code, and can't just use a loop and magically find all the objects (without some more complex coding).

Comment: Hello, I have a question here. If there are functions associted with the dogClass then how I will call them? I do not know the object name when I am creating it with new keyword?

Comment: I have the same question. But I guess the answer is you can't call methods for an object without a name or there's some other syntax than the usual <objectName>.<methodName>. I remember reading something about GetMethod and Invoke somewhere..

Answer (score 3):

There is no way in C# to create names (or in other words identifier) of objects dynamically.

All the above solutions given are right in a sense that they created dynamic objects for you but not dynamic object with a "dynamic NAME".

One roundabout way which may fit your requirement is: by using a keyValue pair.

for example:

```
Dictionary<string, dogClass> DogList = new Dictionary<string, dogClass>(3);
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
DogList.Add("myDog"+i,new dogClass());
}
```

Now to access each of these dogClass from the DogList....u can use->
`DogList["myDog1"]` or `DogList["myDog5"]`......

or if ur dogClass had a property called Name. The Name could be used as the Key.

```
List<dogClass> DogList = new List<dogClass>(3);
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
DogList.Add(new dogClass(Name:"myDog"+i));
}
GetDogWithName("myDog1"); //this method just loops through the List and returns the class that has the Name property set to myDog1
```

Here, for the plain eye or the layman...you have created objects with unique Names. But for you and me...they are strings not the name of the object.

On a funnier thought....
if C# had given us a function(or property) something like this:

```
int myName = 0;
```

now if
  `myName.GetIdentifierName()`

returned "myName".....  uhhhh.. Now i dont want to think beyond this .....what should happen when i set the property to :

```
myName.SetIdentifierName() = "yourName"; //what happens to myName????
```

Answer (score 2):

just use a loop

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
    Doglist.add(new dogClass("puppy" + i.ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for this?

```
for(int i =0; i<100;i++){
   DogList.Add(new dogClass());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to store them in a variable first:

```
DogList.Add(new DogClass());
```

is ok.

If you want to add multiple:

```
DogList.Add(new DogClass());
DogList.Add(new DogClass());
DogList.Add(new DogClass());
```

Or if you want this flexible:

```
for(int i = 0; i < NR_OF_OBJECTS_TO_ADD; i++) {
   DogList.Add(new DogClass());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do that?

Create a method to add a dog:

```
void AddDog()
{
    DogList.Add(new dogClass());
}
```

And access them by index:

```
dogClass GetDog(Int32 index)
{
    return DogList[index];
}
```

Comment: DogList scope is lost after `AddDog`.  It would depend on his / her implementation if DogList is a member of the class or a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    dogClass myDog = new dogClass();
    DogList.Add(myDog);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what are your intentions, but maybe you want to that in a loop:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
     dogList.Add(new DogClass());
  }
```