# How can I dynamically assign object names in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

I want to create the objects of class on a mouse click and then save certain values into the values which I want to retrieve afterwards.

Now I am using the dynamic keyword for this, It works fine with the click and insertion but after that I want to retrieve those saved objects and they are more than one so if use the indexing it does not allow me to use that for the object of type dynamic.

My class name is Container which is a user control. And I want to show that in another class on a tablelayoutpanel mouse click

```
dynamic expando = new Container(); 
int counter = 0;

private void tableLayoutPanel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var pt = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    var colWidths = this.MatrixPanel.GetColumnWidths();
    var rowHeights = this.MatrixPanel.GetRowHeights();
    int col = -1, row = -1;
    int offset = 0;

    for (int iCol = 0; iCol < this.MatrixPanel.ColumnCount; ++iCol)
    {
        if (pt.X >= offset && pt.X <= (offset + colWidths[iCol]))
        {
            col = iCol;
            break;
        }
        offset += colWidths[iCol];
    }
    offset = 0;

    for (int iRow = 0; iRow < this.MatrixPanel.RowCount; ++iRow)
    {
        if (pt.Y >= offset && pt.Y <= (offset + rowHeights[iRow]))
        {
            row = iRow;
            break;
        }
        offset += rowHeights[iRow];
    }
    expando.Name = "Count" + counter;
    MatrixPanel.Controls.Add(expando, col, row);

    expando.setposition(row, col);
    expando.SetChannel(click.ToString());

    counter++;
}
```

Now when I have to retrieve these saved values I have to use the expando list or array How can I declare the List of type Container as well as dynamic?

```
 private void masterTab1_ItemSelected(object sender, object selectedValue)
 {     
    var positions = Adapter.getPositions(RackID);

    for (int i = 0; i < positions.Count; i++)
    {
        MatrixPanel.Controls.Add(expando, positions.ElementAt(i).Y, positions.ElementAt(i).X); // Here I want to use expando[i]

        expando.setposition(positions.ElementAt(i).X, positions.ElementAt(i).Y); // Here I want to use expando[i]
        expando.SetChannel(positions.ElementAt(i).Channel.ToString()); // Here I want to use expando[i]
    }
 }
```

My question is a bit same like [C#, dynamic object names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658726/c-dynamic-object-names) but if I use the new keyword then how will I be able to call the Container functions as I will have no idea about the name of newly created object?

Can anyone has idea how will I be able to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an object at the global scope and add this "*expando*" to "*MatrixPanel*". But this will add same item to "MatrixPanel". So you should create an *object* in the local scope and ad that to "*MatrixPanel*".

I mean in the *tableLayoutPanel1_MouseClick* event create an obhect and add it to *MatrixPanel*. In that place you name it with your counter plus some string.

```
//Instead of this line
expando.Name = "Count" + counter;

//Add this
dynamic expando1 = new Container(); 
expando1.Name = "Count" + counter;
```

You can use the Control Array to get the controls Which are added to the ParentControl("MatrixPanel").

```
Object objControl = MatrixPanel.Controls[index];
```

Like this you have to find out the control. But for this you need index. So make sure you know the index.

Comment: But the problem is I have to use this in another function as well.

Comment: Ya right. You have added it to the parent panel. So you are able to access the control. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I have tried it but is there any way that I can create a list of type Container as well as of dynamic? As far as the insertion is concerned it is working fine but when I have to show all of the created objects to the UI I have to use expando[i] which is not allowed. :/

Comment: Ya you can create a list of container. MatrixPanel.Controls is control array. If you can use this.

Comment: Can you please tell me the syntax? How I will use this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49866/discussion-between-nosheen-javed-and-karthik-amr)