# Create unique names inside loop

Tags: c#, loops

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    List<Object> listName + i = new List<Object>();
    Object objectName + i = new Object();
}
```

I had something like this in mind, but how do I actually do it so it works?

Comment: @krillezzz.. please explain more

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why are you using the `Object` type?

Comment: Not sure how if it can be done. Either way though, the objects fall out of scope outside of the for / with each iteration. So, they effectively wouldn't do anything.

Comment: I wan't to integrate a changeable index to the names. For example var i in this case

Comment: @RyanGates Object in this case is just for example. pinkflydx33 I only need to use them for a calculation inside the loop

Comment: @krillezzz Then why give each loop's variable a different name?

Comment: Use a list, array, dictionary, or some other collection (as the answers note). You should never have variables with "indexed" names.

Comment: @krillezzz variable names have no meaning to compiler (i.e. that how obfuscation is able to replace all variable names with a,aa,aaa...). It is very likely you don't need to create unique variable names, but it is unclear what you actually want - slightly longer sample that shows how you plan to use such "unique names" would clarify the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that.Instead you can use a dictionary:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
    dictionary.Add("myObject" + i, new Object());
}
```

Then you can access your object with `dictionary["myObject1"]`, if that's what you want...

Comment: Given that he wants the names to have an index appended to them, it's *much* more likely that an indexed data structure would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a unique variable name when adding objects to a list in C#.

```
List<int> listName = new List<int>();

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    int objectName = i;
    listName.Add(i);
}
```

Alternatively if you are looking for a KeyValuePair you can use a dictionary.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Object>();

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    dictionary.Add("myObject" + i, new Object());
}
```

You can then access each value using:

```
dictionary["myObject0"]
dictionary["myObject1"]
dictionary["myObject2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    dictionary.Add("Object" + i, new Object());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can dynamically name objects like that. You could try creating a dictionary beforehand and assigning values in a loop. See here, this is similar to what you're looking for:
[C#, dynamic object names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658726/c-dynamic-object-names)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.