# Give objects a name with a variable

Tags: c#, class, object

I'm working on a project where I need to create many objects.
I would like to call the objects player1, player2, player3, etc.

```
Class Player
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<string> NotPlayedAgainst { get; set; }
   public List<string> NotPlayedWith { get; set; }
   public int PositivePoints { get; set; }
   public int NegativePoints { get; set; }
}
```

Now creating the objects by repeating following code:

```
int x = 1;
Player player(x) = new Player();
x++;
```

I need to be able to call the objects using a rule later in the code.
So I would also like to know how to call these objects using a rule like this:

```
player(x).Name = /*some code*/
```

Comment: There is no reason to do that. Use a generic `List<T>` instead and new instances to that list. You will also need to use a `for` loop.

Comment: You can even use a dictionary, give your objects proper names, and enumerate over the keys.

Comment: Generic list, generic dictionary, even a simple array.  Any time you think you want a dynamic variable name, what you *probably* want is a collection.

Comment: As a side note do not name your class `Object`

Comment: This is a X-Y problem. Tell us what you really want to do

Comment: maybe you can also find answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658726/c-dynamic-object-names

Comment: You should post a new question rather than editing this closed question. A new question will get you more visibility and a better chance of an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either add these objects to a `List<Object>` and access them via index or (depending on your real requirement) provide a property to identify the object, for example `Id`:

```
class Object
{
   public Object(int id)
   {
      this.Id = id;
   }

   public int Id { get;}
}
```

---

or both:

```
List<Object> objectList = new List<Object>();
for(int id = 1; id <= 10; id++)
{
    Object objectX = new Object(id);
    objectList.Add(objectX);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have many ways...

**List approach:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>();
        for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            dogs.Add(new Dog());
        }
        Dog firstDog = dogs[0];
    }
}

class Dog
{

}
```

**Array approach:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dog[] dogs = new Dog[100];
        for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            dogs[i] = new Dog();
        }
        Dog firstDog = dogs[0];
    }
}

class Dog
{

}
```

**Dictionary approach:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<int, Dog> dogs = new Dictionary<int, Dog>();
        for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            dogs.Add(i, new Dog());
        }
        Dog firstDog = dogs[0];
    }
}

class Dog
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Dictionary<key, value>`:

```
Dictionary<string, object> objects = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                objects.Add("obj" + i, new object());
            }
```

and to access the object of index 2:

```
object myObj = objects["obj2"];
```